# Android Things and the Google Calendar API

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-things

I'm trying to get a user's Calendar events on the Android Things platform, and found the following tutorial showing a way to do this:
https://medium.com/@F8Full/getaroom-android-things-google-calendar-api-2ab72a5b957f

I've got the authorisation code from the user on the mobile and sent that across to the Android Things device. I've then got to complete the OAuth flow on Android Things but that's where I'm having an issue. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.subs.projecthera/com.subs.projecthera.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1450)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
    at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:158)
    at com.subs.projecthera.Core.AuthHelper.<init>(AuthHelper.java:40)
    at com.subs.projecthera.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7010)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7001)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
```

I have an AuthHelper class:

```
Activity activity;
Context context;

public AuthHelper(String authCode) {
    // Exchange authCode for token
    if (authCode != null) {
        String CLIENT_SECRET_DATA = "{\"web\":{\"client_id\":\"529614308595-q103hbbbktc53tfrudofocg76a390bo1.apps.googleusercontent.com\",\"project_id\":\"smart-mirror-88c35\",\"auth_uri\":\"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth\",\"token_uri\":\"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token\",\"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs\"}}";

        try {
            GoogleClientSecrets GCS = GoogleClientSecrets.load(new JacksonFactory(), new StringReader(CLIENT_SECRET_DATA));
            GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                    new NetHttpTransport(),
                    new JacksonFactory(),
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
                    GCS.getDetails().getClientId(),
                    GCS.getDetails().getClientSecret(),
                    authCode,
                    "" )
                    .execute();

            buildCredentialsAndUpdateActivityModel(tokenResponse);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static GoogleCredential mGoogleCredential;

private void buildCredentialsAndUpdateActivityModel(GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse) {
    String CLIENT_SECRET_DATA = "{\"web\":{\"client_id\":\"529614308595-q103hbbbktc53tfrudofocg76a390bo1.apps.googleusercontent.com\",\"project_id\":\"smart-mirror-88c35\",\"auth_uri\":\"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth\",\"token_uri\":\"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token\",\"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs\"}}";
    try {
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(new JacksonFactory(), new StringReader(CLIENT_SECRET_DATA));

        mGoogleCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                                .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
                                .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
                                .setClientSecrets(clientSecrets).build().setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private boolean storeOAuth2TokenData(String storageID, GoogleCredential toStore) {
    boolean wasStored = false;

    try {
        File oauth2StorageFolder = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "oauth2StorageFolder");
        oauth2StorageFolder.mkdirs();

        FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(oauth2StorageFolder);

        DataStore storedCredentialDataStore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(storageID);//<new StoredCredential()>(storageID)

        //val oauth2Credential = Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod()).setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse)

        StoredCredential storedOAuth2Credential = new StoredCredential(toStore);
        storedCredentialDataStore.set(storageID, storedOAuth2Credential);

        wasStored = true;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        //logInfo("Exception storing OAuth2TokenData :" + exception.localizedMessage)
    }

    return wasStored;
}




private TokenResponse getOAuth2TokenDataFromStore(String storageID) {
    TokenResponse tokenResponse = null;

    try {
        File oauth2StorageFolder = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "oauth2StorageFolder");
        oauth2StorageFolder.mkdirs();

        FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(oauth2StorageFolder);
        DataStore storedCredentialDataStore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(storageID);//<StoredCredential>(storageID);

        StoredCredential storedCredential = (StoredCredential) storedCredentialDataStore.get(storageID);

        if (storedCredential != null) {
            tokenResponse = new TokenResponse();
            tokenResponse.setAccessToken(storedCredential.getAccessToken());
            tokenResponse.setRefreshToken(storedCredential.getRefreshToken());

            if (storedCredential.getExpirationTimeMilliseconds() != null) {
                tokenResponse.setExpiresInSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(storedCredential.getExpirationTimeMilliseconds()));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        //logInfo("Exception getting OAuth2TokenData :" + exception.localizedMessage)
    }

    return tokenResponse;
}
```

And I have a GoogleCalendarHelper:

```
public GoogleCalendarHelper() {
    Calendar calendarAPIClient = new Calendar(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), AuthHelper.mGoogleCredential);

    calendarAPIClient.events();

    Log.e("SOMETHING", "");
}
```

The code is being called from the onCreate method of my MainActivity.

```
    AuthHelper AH = new AuthHelper(GoogleSignIn.getAuthCode(this));
    GoogleCalendarHelper GCH = new GoogleCalendarHelper();
```

I realise that I may have to use AsyncTask, but how would that be implemented in this? Is this the best way to get calendar event information, or is there a better way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error log is quite clear: Network on main thread.

You are doing the calendar request, which is a network request, on the main thread.

You have to do that on the background, some common solutions would be coroutines, RxJava, Callable / Runnable, using a service, managing Threads by hand or even AsyncTask (which is deprecated).

Which solution is really up to you, but long running operations on UI thread are forbidden on both Android and Android Things.